# How can I make the check sign appear after the input element in the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a simple sign up webpage, and want to confirm password and check email address format, and show a check or cross sign after the input elements in the same line.

Before I added Bootstrap to my html file, the check or cross sign appear after the input elements in the same line. But after I added Bootstrap to my html file (especially after adding `class="form-control"`), the check or cross signs appear in the next line instead. 
I wonder how to solve my problem?  Thanks.

[image]

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <style>
      html, body{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: 1px solid black; */
      background: linear-gradient(to top, #f2f6fb, #b3cae3);
      }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script
       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
       src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/register.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-5">

          <form class="form-horizontal" action="RegisterProcess" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
                <span width="5" name="passwordResult" id="passwordResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color\
: white">
                <span width="5" name="passwordConfirmResult" id="passwordConfirmResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
                <span width="5" name="emailResult" id="emailResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-5">
                <input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Sign Up">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function arePasswordsSame() {
    input = this; // document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");                                                                                                                   
    if (input.value != document.getElementById("password").value) {
        input.setCustomValidity("Password Must be Matching.");
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmResult").innerHTML = "&times;";
    } else {
        input.setCustomValidity("");
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmResult").innerHTML = "&#10004;";
    }
}
document.getElementById("passwordConfirm").addEventListener("change",arePasswordsSame);

function validateEmail(){
    input = this; // document.getElementById("email");                                                                                                                             
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(! input.value.match(mailformat)){
    input.setCustomValidity("Email is invalid.");
        document.getElementById("emailResult").innerHTML = "&times;";
    }else{
        input.setCustomValidity("");
        document.getElementById("emailResult").innerHTML = "&#10004;";
    }
}
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("change",validateEmail);
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: what is a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in `input-group-addon` that ships with bootstrap

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
    <span width="5" class="input-group-addon" name="passwordResult" id="passwordResult"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

**EDIT**

This should be the markup;

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
      <span class="input-group-addon" name="passwordResult" id="passwordResult">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. The check and cross signs are still shown  in the next line

Comment: @Tim - I modified your DOM structure a bit to get it to work - theres a working version here https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/c6e888bfae0eb2f693876905062c6fe4 obviously you'll need to adjust styling as you see fit - see my modified answer above to see how I got accomplished it

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap, the `form-control` class causes the `inputs` to be `display:block;` at 100% width. You will have to override the default styling to prevent this(note that you can remove the `!important` rule as long as you add this CSS after Bootstrap is loaded):

```js
function arePasswordsSame() {
    input = this; // document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");                                                                                                                   
    if (input.value != document.getElementById("password").value) {
        input.setCustomValidity("Password Must be Matching.");
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmResult").innerHTML = "&times;";
    } else {
        input.setCustomValidity("");
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmResult").innerHTML = "&#10004;";
    }
}
document.getElementById("passwordConfirm").addEventListener("change",arePasswordsSame);

function validateEmail(){
    input = this; // document.getElementById("email");                                                                                                                             
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(! input.value.match(mailformat)){
    input.setCustomValidity("Email is invalid.");
        document.getElementById("emailResult").innerHTML = "&times;";
    }else{
        input.setCustomValidity("");
        document.getElementById("emailResult").innerHTML = "&#10004;";
    }
}
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("change",validateEmail);
```

```css
.form-control {
  display:inline-block!important;
  width:95%!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <style>
      html, body{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: 1px solid black; */
      background: linear-gradient(to top, #f2f6fb, #b3cae3);
      }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script
       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
       src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/register.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-5">

          <form class="form-horizontal" action="RegisterProcess" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
                <span width="5" name="passwordResult" id="passwordResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="border-color: grey; background-color\
: white">
                <span width="5" name="passwordConfirmResult" id="passwordConfirmResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="border-color: grey; background-color: white">
                <span width="5" name="emailResult" id="emailResult"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-5">
                <input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Sign Up">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the `important` part into `style` element, and move the `style` element to the end of `head` element. Now it only shows cross sign at the end of the `input` element in the same line, but still shows check sign at the next line.

Comment: Both are showing up on the same line in my example above, maybe you need to adjust the width more for your specific implementation?

Comment: Alternatively, if you click "Expand snippet"  in your reply, you can try it online. You will have the same problem as I described in my comment.

Comment: Both the checkmark and the cross are showing up on the same line as the input in my snippet, whether it's expanded or not.

Comment: Did you click "Expand snippet" to test that?

Comment: As I mentioned before, the result is the same regardless of if it's expanded or not.